# In Sublime Text, is there a method to search only across files under version control?

Tags: full-text-search, sublimetext3

Sublime Text's Find in Files feature is handy, but I often wish there were a method (or perhaps a plugin I cannot find) to include only files under version control—or, inversely, to exclude files not under version control.

Ideally I'd *cherish* a `<git tracked files>` tag, similar to the `<open files>` and `<current file>` tags you can use.

Is there a method I could use to achieve this search scope, or a plugin which would allow it?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime's internal Find in Files functionality can be used to search any folder or folders including the ability to add filters to reject or add particular files or file sets, but those filters operate on the path only, not on the contents of the file or any metadata. There is also not an API endpoint for adding new filters to the list or any way for a plugin to interact with the search at all (except to do something to the results once they're generated).

As such, the only way to pull something like this off would be a package/plugin that creates a replacement Find in Files functionality that is more extensible.  I'm not aware of any package that does that myself and I've never come across anyone asking about one previously, but there may be something on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) that does this.

Depending on your use case you might be able to mostly get what you want by excluding untracked files and/or folders from the search. For example a common notion is to redact `node_modules` as largely uninteresting in the general case. That's not really a solution to your particular problem, though.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve been using `-node_modules/` but am looking for a more robust, cross-language solution. Thanks for the thorough reasoning though!